# Regex: Find those links that highlights only one word

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this 2 links that highlights a word `game` , and the second the words, `acapulco heat`

1. `<a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-one.html" class="color-bebe" target="_new">game</a>`
2. `<a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-one.html" class="color-bebe" target="_new">acapulco heat</a>`

I want to use regex as to find those links that highlights only one word, like in the 1 line.

**The output should be:**

`<a href="https://mywebsite.com/page-one.html" class="color-bebe" target="_new">game</a>`

or simple:

`game`

Comment: Mandatory meme comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<a [^>]*"color-bebe".*?>\K\w+(?=</a>)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<a                  # start a tag
[^>]*               # 0 or more any character that is not >
"color-bebe"        # literally
.*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
>                   # >
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
\w+                 # 1 or more word character, you can use \S (non space characters)
(?=</a>)            # positive lookahead, make sure we have the close tag
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Find what: `<a.+>(\w+)</a>`
- Search mode: Regular expression.

optional Replace with: `$1`